# HP Proliant DL320 G5 CPU Fault Light

Tags: hp, hp-proliant

I was recently given an HP Proliant DL320G5.
Upon powering it on the internal health light was flashing red and there was nothing on screen
no beeps no hard drive lights.
I opened the server and powered it back on and there is a CPU fault light glowing.
Is it possible to fix the fault by replacing the CPU or could this be an faulty board indication?

Many thanks

Seb

Answer (score 1):

Bit 50/50 to be honest, it could be either the CPU or the CPU-part-of-the-systemboard, you won't know until you've replaced the CPU sorry. Where are you in the world, I may have a spare G5 Xeon lying around.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. I'm based in the UK and was able to get a replacement CPU. I have fitted this and powered on. It looks like the CPU instead of being red is now amber this is also the same as the ppm light. If you have any ideas of what I can try next I would appreciate the advise?